# Order by most frequent occurrence in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `PAYTB` with transaction information. The table contains `ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM` which is the Common Merchant Name.

Now I want an output like this:

```
orders           ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM     
---------+---------+----------------
100               Antique Shop    
 30               Airleisure    
 23               Books 
 12               ....
```

How can I construct the "orders" column which is the count of all transaction with a certain common merchant name?

Comment: Nothing on Google about COUNTing occurrences of a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group on `ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM` and find count of rows for each, then order by that count in descending order.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) orders,
  ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
FROM PAYTB
GROUP BY ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
ORDER BY orders desc;
```

Comment: @Esperento57 It does. Try it

Comment: @Esperento57 the order by clause is processed at the very last, so the database engine is aware of it at that point. You can't however use alias in having clause as it processed before `select`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) as orders , ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
FROM PAYTB 
GROUP BY ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
ORDER BY 1 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use a group by:

```
select count(*) as orders, ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
       from PAYTB
       group by ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM;
```

Comment: just add order by ;)

Answer (score 0):

Order by count(*) desc to show descending counts in a group by expression.

```
SELECT count(*) as orders , ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
FROM PAYTB 
GROUP BY ACAUREQ_AUREQ_ENV_M_CMONNM
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```